# ¿Qué es un "sobretodo"? ¿Es lo mismo que decir "sobre todo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ortografía, locuciones

En muchas ocasiones me encuentro con textos de este tipo, con la locución adverbial *sobre todo* toda junta:

> Me gusta el fútbol. **Sobretodo** cuando gana mi equipo.

A mí me chirría pues siempre he visto que es *sobre todo*, separado. Sin embargo, muchos editores de textos lo dan por válido y me surge la duda: ¿es correcto decir *sobretodo* en algún caso?

Comment: That is wrong as @fedorqui has explained in his/her answer. Anyway, I wouldn't be surprised to have such a mistake in a football related publication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. *Sobretodo* junto nunca puede sustituir a *sobre todo* separado. Solamente usaremos *sobretodo* para referirnos a una ropa de abrigo.

---

*Sobre todo* quiere decir *especialmente*, *por encima del resto de cosas*, por lo que tu frase correctamente escrita sería:

> Me gusta el fútbol. *Sobre todo* cuando gana mi equipo.

Esto es: *Me gusta el fútbol. Por encima del resto de cosas / especialmente cuando gana mi equipo.*

Sin embargo, sí existe la palabra *sobretodo* y es lo que a veces crea confusión. Ahora bien, es una pieza de vestir:

> [**sobretodo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YAdNkiH)
>
> 1. m. Prenda de vestir ancha, larga y con mangas, en general más ligera que el gabán, que se lleva sobre el traje ordinario.
> 2. m. Am. Abrigo o impermeable que se lleva sobre las demás prendas.

El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas habló de ello en su artículo [*todo, -da*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=4ZoJDrD4zD6V2e1muq):

> 9. **sobre todo**. ‘Especialmente, principalmente’: *«Me encanta la música ligera, sobre todo cuando es lenta»* (Nieva Señora [Esp. 1980]). Es locución adverbial y se escribe siempre en dos palabras. **No debe confundirse con *sobretodo*, sustantivo masculino que significa ‘prenda de vestir, larga y con mangas, que se lleva encima de las demás prendas’ y que, en América, se emplea como sinónimo de *abrigo***: *«Albert Camus posa con el cuello del sobretodo levantado para enfrentar el frío parisino»* (González *Habano* [Cuba 1998]).

Comment: En invierno uso sobre todo un sobretodo.

Comment: @blonfu nunca voy olvidar lo que es un sobretodo. Gracias.

Comment: Curious fact: In Portuguese, both words are translated to "sobretudo".